# Connection problems between Access Point and Ubuntu

Tags: wireless-access-point, nmap

I have an access point already configured (with another AP and it's 3 IP cameras) and I can  get in with a WinXP laptop (by AP's IP address) who is wired connected, directly to the AP.

Now, I want to mount an Ubuntu computer to stay connected as my laptop is. There is not any difference, only OS.

First of all, I was trying to get in the AP (via browser and AP IP addr) like this:

AP and Ubuntu desktop connected to a switch, and this connected to a router (The IP address of the AP is static). With this, I can't get in to the AP. Even so, writing in terminal **nmap -A -PN 192.168.1.123**, I get this:
"*Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 hosts up) scanned in 201.64 sec*"

With this, I understand that my computer CAN see the AP right :O?

PD: Doing this with my computer connected directly to the AP via eth cable it's the same thing.

Sorry about my English and Thanks!

Diego V.

Answer (score 1):

Nmap is indicating that 192.168.1.123 is up, but it did not find any open ports from the common ports list that it uses.

1. First test you can Ping the IP address of the AP from both computers.
2. Then you can use Nmap to see if the port on the AP is open (nmap -p 8080 192.168.1.123), change 8080 to whatever port you use when accessing from your XP machine.